# How can I return each record associated with State and City while returning State and City name only once? (MySql)

Tags: mysql

I'm not really sure how to ask this and I've been search-engining for awhile and haven't come up with anything useful.

Say I have the following three tables `People`, `Cities` and `States`:

```
PeopleID |   Name   |    Age   | CityIDFK
--------------------------------------------
     1   |   John   |    24    |      20 
     2   |   Jim    |    28    |      21 
     3   |   Joan   |    49    |      10 
     4   |   Mike   |    37    |      10 
     5   |   Bruce  |    26    |      2 
     6   |   Peter  |    22    |      20 
     7   |   Oprah  |    27    |      3 
     7   |   Jake   |    21    |      1
```

```
CityIDPK |    City     |   StateIDFK
---------------------------------------
     1     |  Seattle    |      1 
     2     |  Gotham     |      2 
     3     |  Oakland    |      4 
     10    |  Boise      |      5 
     20    |  Austin     |      6 
     21    |  Tyler      |      6
```

```
StateIDPK    |   StateName
----------------------------
      1      |   Washington
      2      |   New York
      3      |   Oregon
      4      |   California
      5      |   Idaho
      6      |   Texas
```

How can I achieve the following output:

```
    StateName |   City     |    Name    
---------------------------------------
California    |   Oakland  |    Oprah  
Idaho         |   Boise    |    Mike  
              |            |    Joan
New York      |   Gotham   |    Bruce
Washington    |   Seattle  |    Jake
Texas         |   Austin   |    John
              |            |    Peter
              |   Tyler    |    Jim
```

I'm not sure if the above output is possible or not, I would probably just do something like this:

```sql
SELECT StateName, City, Name FROM People
INNER JOIN Cities
ON Cities.CityIDPK = People.CityIDFK
INNER JOIN States
ON States.StateIDPK = Cities.StateIDFK
```

But that would return the `StateName` and `City` for every person, instead of just once.

```
    StateName |   City     |    Name    
---------------------------------------
California    |   Oakland  |    Oprah  
Idaho         |   Boise    |    Mike  
Idaho         |   Boise    |    Joan 
New York      |   Gotham   |    Bruce
Washington    |   Seattle  |    Jake
Texas         |   Austin   |    John
Texas         |   Austin   |    Peter
Texas         |   Tyler    |    Jim
```

If the output I want to achieve is possible, would someone show me an example of how to write the query, or point me in the right direction?

Comment: This is a requirement which might be best handled in your presentation layer (e.g. something like PHP or Java).  If you do really need this directly in MySQL, then can you tell us what version of MySQL you are using?

Comment: Handle issues of data display in application code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with Tim, this should be handled in your presentation layer.

But you can do it if you're using MySQL 8 by taking advantage of [window functions](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-window-functions/). We can use [`row_number()`](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-window-functions/mysql-row_number-function/) to determine the first row per state and per city, then use a [case](https://www.w3schools.com/SQL/func_mysql_case.asp) to only display the name for the first row.

```
SELECT
  case row_number() over states_w
    when 1 then states.name
    else '' end as StateName,
  case row_number() over cities_w
    when 1 then cities.name
    else '' end as CityName,
  people.name as Name
FROM People
INNER JOIN Cities ON Cities.id = People.City_id
INNER JOIN States ON States.id = Cities.state_id
window states_w as (partition by states.id),
  cities_w as (partition by cities.id);
```

If you're using MySQL before 8... upgrade. If you can't upgrade, [it can be emulated](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-row_number/).

Comment: Thanks all, I'll do it with c#, just wondering if it was easily possible this way, appreciate the responses!